# Problem settingup a play command for my discord bot (music) ['Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!']

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js, ytdl

Im new to programing a discord bot, im more to the web developing enviroment, im trying to create by myself a play command song (only with one link) to try if the first join is working and actually play the song.

(Discord.js v14)

Unfortunately i was having a problem with FFMPEG.
This my actual module for the play.js command, where all the problem is happening.

```
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

module.exports = {
    devOnly: true,
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Start to play a song!',
    // options: Object[],

    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Interaction} interaction
     */
    callback: async (client, interaction) => {
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return interaction.reply('You must be in a voice channel to use this command.');
        }

        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: interaction.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });

        const stream = ytdl('URL_HERE', { filter: 'audioonly' });
        const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        connection.subscribe(player);
        player.play(resource);

        interaction.reply({
            content: `Playing Song`,
            // ephemeral: true,
        });
    }
}
```

The first error i was receving was 'Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!', i tried to install it with some guides online. after couple of tries i get it right and the command 'ffmpeg -version' returns.

After that i tought it was workikng, but when i started my project, i receved the same error,. I tried to look up for a solution and i tried to get the process.env.PATH to see but i dont understand if its right or not.

After i removed the console.log(process.env.PATH), i get no errors in the terminal, but it will stil not play the song.

Answer (score 0):

```js
     const stream = ytdl(ytdl.getURLVideoID(url), {
       filter: format => format.audioCodec === 'opus' && format.container === 'webm',
       quality: 'highest',
       highWaterMark: 32 * 1024 * 1024,
     });
     const resource = createAudioResource(stream, {
       inputType: StreamType.WebmOpus
     });
```

try specifying stream type. (`StreamType` is including in @discordjs/voice)

---

Old answer:
Try `npm i tweetnacl ffmpeg-static @discordjs/opus`. Discord.js v14 Voice can play with ffmpeg-static

Comment: Unfortunately its not resolving the same problem of connecting and not playing the link

Comment: Can you provide a result of `require("@discordjs/voice").generateDependencyReport()` ?

Comment: `--------------------------------------------------
Core Dependencies
- @discordjs/voice: 0.16.0
- prism-media: 1.3.5

Opus Libraries
- @discordjs/opus: 0.9.0
- opusscript: not found

Encryption Libraries
- sodium-native: not found
- sodium: not found
- libsodium-wrappers: not found
- tweetnacl: 1.0.3

FFmpeg
- version: 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev
- libopus: yes
--------------------------------------------------`

i dont know if im using this correctly, but this is what i get in return

Comment: what you mean by edited?

Comment: Please see the new content added to my response

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, the error now is not shwoing up, but event with this, its still not playing thelink, and its not playing anything

The other problem is that i dont get any type of errors either.

Comment: One thing i notice with some trouble shooting i did, is that the "Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!" it will actually shows up sometimes, an not always